# "Как идиот" — выделяется запятыми или нет?

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, выделяется ли выражение "как идиот" запятыми в таком предложении:

Я(,) как идиот(,) поплелся к ней домой, а там меня, конечно, никто не ждал.

Answer (score 2):

*Я **как идиот** поплелся к ней домой, а там меня, конечно, никто не ждал.*

1) Полагаю, что подходить к обособлению оборота формально не стоит. Он имеет признаки устойчивого сочетания и **может быть как необособленным обстоятельством, так и  попутным сравнением.** Многое зависит от структуры предложения и постановки логических ударений.

2) В частности в данном предложении оборот лучше не обособлять, так как   логически выделено сочетание ***я как идиот***, там нет паузы. Сравнить: *Я **совершенно неразумно** поплелся к ней домой, а там меня, конечно, никто не ждал.*

В другой позиции оборот обособляется, являясь попутным сравнением: *Я поплелся, **как идиот**, к ней домой, а там меня, конечно, никто не ждал.*

3) Рассмотрим примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Я, **как идиот**, вскакиваю, бегаю по комнате, ищу выход. [Вячеслав Тимохин. Как я гостил у американского миллионера (1997) // «Столица», 1997.01.06]  Ударение падает на однородные сказуемые, оборот обособляется.

А я **как идиот** (= по-идиотски) взревел: «Никогда не разлюблю!» [Михаил Чулаки. Прощай, зеленая Пряжка (1998)]

Comment: Точно, *устойчивое сочетание!* Вот выражение, которое я искал. (Забыл поставить пробел, поэтому отправил заново.)

Answer (score 1):

Меняю ответ. Бот заставил меня задуматься, и я понял, что однобоко подошёл к решению этого вопроса.

Действительно, тут нет непосредственного сравнения с идиотом, это выражение можно заменить наречием, которое передаёт тот же смысл.

Об этом случае говорится [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827524.html) (§ 42.4):

> Обороты с союзом *как* не выделяются запятыми:
>
> 1) если на первый план выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия (обороты с как можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием): ***Как град*** посыпалась картечь (Л.) (ср.: *посыпалась градом);  **Как демон** коварна и зла* (Л.) (ср.: *демонически коварна); В гневе он **как гром** загремел, **как сталь** засверкал; Конь **как буран**  летит, **как вьюга**  спешит; **Как зарницы** в небе они запылали, **как огненный дождь** с неба упали; Я посмотрел на неё **как дурак*** (Т.).

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, обособление не требуется. Предыдущий комментатор неверно выразился, не рассмотрев все возможные вариации смысла. Теперь разберемся с самим предложением. "Разобьем" сложное предложение на два простых, из которых  нас интересует первое:

"Я поплёлся за ней как идиот" В данном случае найдем грамматическую основу и увидим, что "поплёлся" будет выполнять роль сказуемого без каких-либо дополнительных сочетаний. Найдем  зависимые слова и обратим внимание на необходимое сочетание. Здесь можно выстроить следующую связь: поплёлся (как?) как идиот. Для проверки постараемся заменить необходимое сочетание более простым: поплёлся (как?) опрометчиво. Получаем, что данное сочетание имеет связь с глаголом, заключающуюся в признаке, то есть является обстоятельством, причем образа действия.